# Add a checkbox within a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a todo list and am trying to create a delete button.  I'm going to make the delete button a checkbox, but I'm not sure how to add it to my task.

```js
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {
        var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox' id='newtasklist' class='right-margin' <label>" + newTask + "</label></li>");
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });

  $('body').on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.right-margin {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="newtaskitem" class="right-margin"><label>test</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did the edit fix it?

Comment: Nope, it was just some rearranging.

Comment: When I clicked Run Code Snippet it seemed to work, What's your expected outcome then? Is not clear from the question

Comment: I'm trying to add a delete button right next to the side of the text of the tasks, that when clicked, will make the task completely disappear.

Comment: Why do you want to use a checkbox? why not use a regular button and have an event listener that deletes it, using an id or the index or parent selector

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a checkbox in a checkbox, it doesn't really make sense. How would the browser know what to act upon.

To solve your problem, I've added an additional checkbox which is hidden by CSS, the label for it used to toggle  the check box.

Then we use jQuery to find the items with the delete check box checked and remove the parent `li`

```js
$(() => {
  let idx = 0;
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {

        //Use a template literal, it makes replacing things easier. Use a counter
        //to make sure id's are uniqe
        idx++;
        var li = $(`<li><input type='checkbox' id='newtasklist${idx}' name="done" class='right-margin'><input type='checkbox' id='delete${idx}' name="delete" value="newtaskitem${idx}"><label>${newTask}</label><label class="delete" title="Select item for removal" for='delete${idx}'>♻</label></li>`);
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        
      }
    }
  });
 
  $("#deleteItems").on("click", function(){
    //find checked delete checkboxes and iterate them
    $("#tasksUL [name=delete]:checked").each(function(){
      //find the parent list item and remove it
      $(this).closest("li").remove();
    })
  })

});
```

```css
/*We can do the decoration with CSS*/
#tasksUL input[name=done]:checked~label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.right-margin {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

/*Hide the delete check box - use the label instead*/
[type="checkbox"][name="delete"] {display:none;}


.delete {margin-left:1em;}

/*Change the appearence when marked for deletion*/
#tasksUL input[name=delete]:checked ~ label {color:#ccc; font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="newtaskitem0" name="done" class="right-margin">
  <input type='checkbox' id='delete${idx}' name="delete" value="newtaskitem0"><label>test</label><label for='delete${idx}' class="delete" title="Select item for removal">♻</label></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Delete marked items" id="deleteItems">
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves the issue.

```js
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {
        var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox' id='newtasklist' class='right-margin' <label>" + newTask + "</label></li>");
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });

  $('body').on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
  });
  $(".delete-btn").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.right-margin {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.delete-btn {
  display: none;
}
.selected .delete-btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="newtaskitem" class="right-margin">
    <label>test</label>
    <button type="button" class="delete-btn">Del</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```